# android deprecation situation

Tags: android, eclipse

I got some sample code for `TabLayout` for Android and I modified it to suit my needs.

The thing is that when I tried to re-write it I got some deprecation errors and when i opened the sample no errors appeared.

At first I thought it was the `minSdkversion` so i changed it in the sample but still nothing happened.

I can't get the icons appear correctly in the tab so it might have something to do with this deprecation.

Can anyone enlight me? Here is my code:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
//notice that here eclipse won't let me import android.widget.TabHost
//but i use it when i create the tabhost variable

public class TabHost extends TabActivity {
    //the 'TabActivity' part above gets crossed-over although that doesn't happen
    //in the sample
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_host);

        android.widget.TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabSpec absSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Absences");
        absSpec.setIndicator("Absences", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abs));
        Intent int1 = new Intent(this, Absences.class);
        absSpec.setContent(int1);
        tabHost.addTab(absSpec);
    }
}
```

and this is the sample :

```
package com.example.androidtablayout;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
        photospec.setIndicator("Photos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
        photospec.setContent(photosIntent);
        tabHost.addTab(photospec); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why not show us the "some deprecation errors", what lines they were, etc? That might be helpful :)

Comment: ok as i say the when i extend TabActivity it gets crossed-over and the error mark say that tabActivity is deprecated.The other thing that i just realised is that i'm an idiot the reason that won't let me import tabhost is that i stupidily named my class tabhost.The deprecation of the tabActivity though still stands...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TabActivity is deprecated, you should use fragments and the compatibly library to implement tabs now. Google seems to be pushing this deprecation quite forcefully, and they have even replaced the documentation page with a "how to migrate" type page.So http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html now explains what needs to be done to port your code :)

Comment: oh so this is the only way that it can be done now? ok i will read it thanx for guiding me :)

Comment: its certainly the way to go :) google around as well, there is quite a few blogs, tutorials etc on how to do fragment based tabs :)

Comment: Well that's really helpfull i want torned whether to use tabs or fragments anyway but i thought i would be difficult hope i will manage it,it will look better for sure though,so thx